# How to offer financing to customers (Used Car Dealership)?

Tags: car, business, start-up, financing

I'm have used car dealership and I would like to offer financing options for my customers (Lately many potentials buyers ask for such). Does anyone knows from where I can start ?  What company does that automotive financing that work with dealers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about running a business rather than personal finance.

Comment: @NathanL I will remove it, is there any other SE portal I can post it to?

Comment: No, I think the closest would be legal because there are certainly many applicable laws you should be aware of, but as far as how to create a relationship with a bank or credit union to offer financing, that's just something you'll have to explore by approaching a few of them.

Comment: I agree with the fact that many laws involve in this. But It also has financial decision side to this question. I only find Personal Finance & Money that would fit this question better, or Startup portal (Should I post it there?).

Comment: I believe this question would be technically on topic in Startup: http://startups.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Up to their community if they'd be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I would outsource as much as possible with the desire to receive up front payment from financing companies for originating a loan.  Why?

The biggest risk to newer businesses is cash flow.  The amount of work a new business owner has to do is daunting.  If you can outsource some of that work it will increase your chance of success and make your life easier.  Focus on selling cars.

The upfront origination will help with your cash flow.

If you can outsource the credit decision making and paper work you have leveraged your time and can focus on more important things.

Comment: This is awesome. I had that in mind too. Very useful validation. I just can't find companies who I can outsource such a service (Financing).

Comment: @FarhadSaadatpei Talk to local credit unions and locally-owned banks.  They will often partner with car dealerships to offer auto loans to purchasers.  (The last car loan I took was through a local credit union.  I signed up right at the used car dealership the day I purchased the car.)